# Maven exec with classunloading

Tags: maven

How can I pass the classunloading parameter to mvn?

mvn -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled  exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Test"

Whats the correct format to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec:java` goal executes the main class in the **[current JVM](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)**. That means you need to run Maven itself with the JVM arguments you need. A good way to pass JVM arguments to Maven is via the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable:

```
$ export MAVEN_OPTS=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Test"
```